# Create inline array using multiple MySql columns

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So, I have a MySQL query that returns a number of results (in this case, different currencies for products). They appear in the table like this:

```
Product Name  |  Euros  |  Dollars  |  GBP  |  Stock?
_______________________________________________
Acme Produce  |  34.00  |  52.00  |  30.00  |  "In Stock"
MoreProducts  | 153.00  | 160.00  | 144.00  |  "In Stock"
```

I want to be able to print it out in PHP all on one line (sounds silly when you have information in a table, I know, but there is a reason for it) like this

> "You have a number of products including 'Acme Produce', currently
>   selling for E34.00, $52.00, £30.00 in stock, and 'MoreProducts',
>   currently selling for E153.00, $160.00, £144.00 in stock which you
>   have not looked at for a while"

How do I possibly construct a string for this?!

I get the products from MySQL using the following:

```
$query_productDetails = sprintf("SELECT * FROM ProductsView")
$query_limit_productDetails = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_productDetails, $startRow_productDetails, $maxRows_productDetails);
$productDetails = mysql_query($query_limit_productDetails, $Products) or die(mysql_error());
$row_productDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($productDetails);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_productDetails'])) {
  $totalRows_productDetails = $_GET['totalRows_productDetails'];
} else {
  $all_productDetails = mysql_query($query_productDetails);
  $totalRows_productDetails = mysql_num_rows($all_productDetails);
}
```

and then get the individual columns in a `<?php echo $row_productDetails['GBP']; ?>` (for example).

How do I get this information into an array, so that I can put it together in the desired format?

Comment: Off topic but is it wise to save the prices as fixed values for different currencies rather that using rates?

Comment: A good point - but there is a boring contractual reason for this method.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do it like this:

```
$lines = array();
foreach ($row_productDetails) {
    $lines[] = "'{$row_productDetails['NAME']}', currently selling for E{$row_productDetails['EUR']}, ${$row_productDetails['USD']}, £{$row_productDetails['GBP']} {$row_productDetails['InStock']}";
}

var_dump(implode(", and "));
```

Comment: Actually... that's pretty neat! I had been trying a bizarre series of implodes and explodes... but this is sweet! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: One more thing - there seems to be a syntax error on the second line - is there a missing bracket here?

Comment: It was written as example, you have to iterate thru your rows